# What is UX writing?

Tags: technical-writing

What is UX writing? I am a writer and a UX designer by trade. I hear a lot about UX writing being the next big thing. Should I specialize in this area?

Comment: McCoy, what have you found in your research? My internet search immediately turned up the (somewhat obvious) answer that "A UX writer is someone who writes for user experience. UX writers write the words we read or hear when we use a digital product." We can't possibly answer your second question, any more than we can advise whether you should have pasta for dinner tonight. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the [Tour] of our site. :-)

Comment: Great field to know of. Nothing that Google cannot help you get acquainted with. Let's have a more focused discussion here when you've read through the popular articles like Wikipedia, uxplanet.com, uxdesign.cc, etc top sites. Some such sites are involved enough to provide industry-recognized certifications on UX writing. These sites are no wonder at the top of search results and no wonder they offer great introductions and reading materials. In fact, there are a few books written on the subject if you'd like to go through one.

Answer (score 1):

I typed "UX writing" into Google and found [this article](https://careerfoundry.com/en/blog/ux-design/ux-writing-what-does-a-ux-writer-actually-do/) on the first page, which explains the concept quite well:

> UX writing is the art of crafting the texts that appear throughout the interface of digital products (websites, mobile apps, etc.). Just as in the world of traditional publishing, this text is referred to as copy. But UX writing differs from copywriting in that it aims to guide the user through the interface in an intuitive manner.

An example of UX writing would be the messages that appear when a question is closed here on Stack Exchange. They need to be clear enough for users to understand why their question was closed, but polite enough that (most) users won't misinterpret the closure as a personal attack. Even things like the names of the menu items on the left-hand side of the screen count as UX writing.

As for whether you should specialise in UX writing, that's something you'll need to decide for yourself. We're not qualified to give out career advice.